# While loop doesn't stop when number is power of 2

Tags: python, while-loop, factorization

I have some issues in python console app.
I coded an factorization console app.
It works well, but when I input a number that is power of 2 like 4, 8, 16, the while loop doesn't stop.
So it doesn't print anything and the code doesn't stop.
Bellow is my code.

```
import math

n=input("Input check number:")
n=int(n)
sent= str(n) + "=1"

for m in range(2, int(n / 2)+1):
    if n % m == 0:
        k = n
        i = 0
        while k % m == 0:
            k = k / m
            i += 1
        sent = sent + "*" + str(m) + "^" + str(i)

if sent == str(n)+ "=1":
    sent = sent + "*" + str(n)

print(sent)
```

I want someone to help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: because you don't change `n` or `m` inside the `while` loop so for input `n=4`, `m=2`, `k` comes out to be `n/m=2` which satisfies `k%m==0` and neither `n` nor `m` changes so it runs forever.

Comment: If `n` if 4 (for example) then the first time through the `for` loop `m` will be 2 and `k = n / m` will just keep setting `k` to 2 over and over again, which satisfies the `while` loop condition.

Comment: I changed k as n/m every time k%m==0. And i is counter of m. I want to show like 18=1*2^1*3^2.

Comment: Here, 2, 3 after * are m and 1, 2 after ^ are i.

Comment: I changed k = k/m. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't change `n` or `m` inside the `while` loop. So, for example, for input `n=4`, `m=2`, `k` comes out to be `n/m=2` which satisfies `k%m==0` and since neither `n` nor `m` changes so it runs forever.

You can simplify the code by modifying `n` in the while `loop` to keep decreasing if it is divisible by the current divisor `m`. You can't do the same for `k` since `k` is reset to `n` again with the line `k = n` and it will start with the original number giving incorrect output.

Here is a bit modified version of the code with the outer `while` loop:

```
n=input("Input check number:")
n = int(n)
sent = str(n) + "=1"

m = 2  # start division with 2
while n > 1: # keep dividing till the number is greater than 1
    if m > n:
        break
    i = 0
    while n % m == 0:
        n = n / m   # modify n by dividing it with current divisor
        i += 1
    
    if i > 0: # add only if m divides n at least once
        sent = sent + "*" + str(m) + "^" + str(i)

    m = m + 1

if sent == str(n)+ "=1":
    sent = sent + "*" + str(n)

print(sent)
```

Output (for input `18`):

```
18=1*2^1*3^2
```

Comment: can you describe the input you tried? I can try to fix it.

Comment: At first, I tried 4. Then, I tried 9. They didn't stop loop.

Comment: I get the expected result without any issues: `Input check number:4`, Output: `4=1*2^2`. Same for `9`: `Input check number:9`, Output: `9=1*3^2`.

Comment: When I first try it, It didn't stop because m increases infinitely. I added some codes that can stop m until sqrt(n). It works now. Thank you.

Comment: I found some issues. This is my try. 456789322894537527276811747671848721=1*3^5*4^32

Comment: As you can see, the input number is odd number. And how can it work like 4^32?

Comment: And see it. 2345=1*5^1*7^1

Comment: yes, the code is not that optimized, it is just a brute force solution so it will take time if the number and the divisors are big.

Comment: I understand. I will stop loop when m>n. It works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228886/discussion-between-krishna-chaurasia-and-george).